# Cross origin request domain to subdomain

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send xhttp request in javascript. My both domain and subdomain are https secured. Applied `allowed Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * / example.com` header as true but still i am getting. Tried jquery ajax as well javascript xml http request. For example domain name like as example.com, blog.another.com, Subdomain is of different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most common error , Even after implement as given solutions , But i would suggest send request with credential parameter.

try it   `xhttp.withCredentials = true;`

Hope it will work if you already tried `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`